# How to make macbook pro recognize GLEW and GLFW?

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw, glew

I am new to macbook and apple computers in general, so I'm having a hard time making macbook pro recognize GLEW and GLFW.  I installed both libraries with no problem, my includes are as follows:  /usr/include/GL for glew.h, glxew.h and wglew.h.  /usr/lib/ contains libGLEW.a  the include and lib files for GLFW are in /usr/local/  I am using vim as a text editor and have a simple main.cpp program but it gives me an error that the glew.h cannot be found, any ideas why this is happening and how should I fix it?

```
#include <GL/glew.h>

#define GLFW_DLL
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  if (!glfwInit())
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW\n");
    return 1;
  }

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow (640, 480, "Hello Shaders", NULL, NULL);
  if (!window)
  {   fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not openwindow with GLFW3\n");
    glgwTerminate();
    return 1;
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent (window);

  glewExperimantal = GL_TRUE;
  glewInit();

  const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
  const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
  printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
  printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

  glEnable (DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc (GL_LESS);

  glfwTerminate();

  return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with:

```
g++ -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -o demo main.cpp -I include -I/sw/include -I/usr/local/include /usr/lib/libGLEW.a /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a
```

Edit: moving the GL includes to /usr/local fixed compilation errors but now I get a linker error, any idea what can be done here?

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.10.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 241.9 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -I include -I /sw/include -I /usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/yuri13/Documents/shaders -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.10.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/b4/j5zrzg_n7hb205xs22z5f4qc0000gp/T/main-ea70be.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 6.0 based upon LLVM 3.5svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/sw/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -o demo -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit /var/folders/b4/j5zrzg_n7hb205xs22z5f4qc0000gp/T/main-ea70be.o /usr/lib/libGLEW.a /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CVDisplayLinkGetNominalOutputVideoRefreshPeriod", referenced from:
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CVDisplayLinkRelease", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Tacking `-v` onto the `g++` command line might tell you a bit more about where it’s looking for it.

Comment: @icktoofay thanks, as soon as I moved GL includes into /usr/local/ it compiled but now I get a linker error, which I will post in the edit above.

Comment: I searched and found [this forum post](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/fix-for--cvdisplaylinkrelease-etc-errors/16423) which says that you need to add `-framework CoreVideo`.

Comment: GLEW is completely unnecessary on OS X. All extension functions are available at link-time instead of run-time; in other words, instead of having `NULL` pointers for unsupported functions, on OS X you get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` errors when you try to call an unsupported extension. You should actually just write some statement to the effect `#ifndef __APPLE__ ... #endif` around anything GLEW-related in your code.

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks adding -framework CoreVideo worked.  Would you mind making that into an answer in case others run into the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get an error related to including the header file, the compiler cannot find the header. You can pass the `-v` flag to GCC (incl. `g++`) or Clang (incl. `clang++`) to see information about where it’s looking for it.

---

As [this forum post](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/fix-for--cvdisplaylinkrelease-etc-errors/16423) explains, if you receive these link errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CVDisplayLinkGetNominalOutputVideoRefreshPeriod", referenced from:
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CVDisplayLinkRelease", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Then you probably need to link with the `CoreVideo` framework. If you’re compiling on the command line, you can use `-framework CoreVideo`.